# How can I select data from multiple SQL tables?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, as described below:

**Grades**

```
student id, 
exem1, 
exam2, 
exam3
```

**Names**

```
student id, 
names
```

I want to display the names of students, their average on the 3 exams, and a letter grade. The letter grade is computed as follows:

`90+ is an “A”`, `80 - <90 will be a “B”`, and so on. How should i do it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> SELECT n.student_names, ((g.exam1+g.exam2+g.exam3)/3) AS 'AVERAGE_RESULT', (CASE 
              WHEN ((g.exam1+g.exam2+g.exam3)/3) =90  
                 THEN 'A' 
              WHEN (((g.exam1+g.exam2+g.exam3)/3) BETWEEN 80 AND 89)  
                 THEN 'B' 
              WHEN (((g.exam1+g.exam2+g.exam3)/3) BETWEEN 70 AND 79)  
                 THEN 'C' 
              ELSE 'D') END AS 'Student_grades',
FROM names n, grades g
WHERE n.students_id = g.students_id;
```

Using BETWEEN to include the ranges

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT n.NAME AS "Name", CASE WHEN ((g.exam1+g.exam2+g.exam3)/3) = 90 then 'A'
 WHEN ((g.exam1+g.exam2+g.exam3)/3) < 90 then 'B'
 ELSE 'C'
 END AS "Grade"
FROM NAMES AS n INNER JOIN GRADES AS g 
ON g.student_id = n.student_id
```

Modify the ranges as you want.

Comment: Mine was very similar-s.sql("""select n._2,(((sum(g._2))+(sum(g._3))+(sum(g._4)))/3) as Average,Case when (((sum(g._2))+(sum(g._3))+(sum(g._4)))/3) < 90 then 'B' else 'C' end as Grade from names n inner join grades g on n._1 = g._1 group by(n._2)""")